# how to add header text with adjacent content in un-formatted data set, side by side with a delimiter separated value using sed/awk/python

Tags: python, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a long list of unformatted data say data.txt where each set is started with a header and ends with a blank line, like:

```
TypeA/Price:20$
alexmob
moblexto
unkntom

TypeB/Price:25$
moblexto2
unkntom0
alexmob3
poptop9
tyloret

TypeC/Price:30$
rtyuoper0
kunlohpe6
mobryhox
```

Now, i want to add the header of each set with it's content side by side with comma separated. Like:

```
alexmob,TypeA/Price:20$
moblexto,TypeA/Price:20$
unkntom,TypeA/Price:20$

moblexto2,TypeB/Price:25$
unkntom0,TypeB/Price:25$
alexmob3,TypeB/Price:25$
poptop9,TypeB/Price:25$
tyloret,TypeB/Price:25$

rtyuoper0,TypeC/Price:30$
kunlohpe6,TypeC/Price:30$
mobryhox,TypeC/Price:30$
```

so that whenever i will grep with one keyword, relevant content along with the header comes together. Like:

```
$grep mob data.txt
alexmob,TypeA/Price:20$
moblexto,TypeA/Price:20$
moblexto2,TypeB/Price:25$
alexmob3,TypeB/Price:25$
mobryhox,TypeC/Price:30$
```

I am newbie on bash scripting as well as python and recently started learning these, so would really appreciate any simple bash scipting (using sed/awk) or python scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/Type/{h;d;};/[a-z]/{G;s/\n/,/}' input_file
alexmob,TypeA/Price:20$
moblexto,TypeA/Price:20$
unkntom,TypeA/Price:20$

moblexto2,TypeB/Price:25$
unkntom0,TypeB/Price:25$
alexmob3,TypeB/Price:25$
poptop9,TypeB/Price:25$
tyloret,TypeB/Price:25$

rtyuoper0,TypeC/Price:30$
kunlohpe6,TypeC/Price:30$
mobryhox,TypeC/Price:30$
```

Match lines containing `Type`, hold it in memory and delete it.

Match lines with alphabetic characters, append `G` the contents of the hold space. Finally, sub new line for a comma.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Can you please share little explanation of  
```
/Type/{h;d;};/[a-z]/{G;s/\n/,/}
```

Comment: @Rafailo Please check edit

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation, now I got it. but I observed that if any line ends with Capital letter, there [a-z] not working rather [A-Z] working. so, what can I use to capture both capital and small letter?

Comment: @Rafailo Use `[A-Za-z]` or `[[:alpha:]]`   `sed '/Type/{h;d;};/[[:alpha:]]/{G;s/\n/,/}' file`

Answer (score 1):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
TypeA/Price:20$
alexmob
moblexto
unkntom

TypeB/Price:25$
moblexto2
unkntom0
alexmob3
poptop9
tyloret

TypeC/Price:30$
rtyuoper0
kunlohpe6
mobryhox
```

then

```
awk '/^Type/{header=$0;next}{print /./?$0 ";" header:$0}' file.txt
```

output

```
alexmob;TypeA/Price:20$
moblexto;TypeA/Price:20$
unkntom;TypeA/Price:20$

moblexto2;TypeB/Price:25$
unkntom0;TypeB/Price:25$
alexmob3;TypeB/Price:25$
poptop9;TypeB/Price:25$
tyloret;TypeB/Price:25$

rtyuoper0;TypeC/Price:30$
kunlohpe6;TypeC/Price:30$
mobryhox;TypeC/Price:30$
```

Explanation: If line starts with (`^`) `Type` set `header` value to that line (`$0`) and go to `next` line. For every line `print` if it does contain at least one character (`/./`) line (`$0`) concatenated with `;` and `header`, otherwise print line (`$0`) as is.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box regardless of which characters are in your data:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' -v OFS=',' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $i, $1; print ""}' file
alexmob,TypeA/Price:20$
moblexto,TypeA/Price:20$
unkntom,TypeA/Price:20$

moblexto2,TypeB/Price:25$
unkntom0,TypeB/Price:25$
alexmob3,TypeB/Price:25$
poptop9,TypeB/Price:25$
tyloret,TypeB/Price:25$

rtyuoper0,TypeC/Price:30$
kunlohpe6,TypeC/Price:30$
mobryhox,TypeC/Price:30$
```

Comment: would you please add some explanation of your awk command.

Comment: @Rafailo It's all just basic awk using simple constructs explained in the man page so we can't explain all the basics in every answer but if after a look at the man page you let me know what part of it still isn't clear then I'll explain that part.